# Поиск одинаковых символов в строке и их замена. Какие функции лучше использовать?

Tags: c, строки

нужно использовать библиотеку ***string.h***

Использовать можно только массив со строкой, нельзя использовать доп.массив для хранения новой строки

ввод происходит через ***gets()***

Имеется строка, в которой может встретиться несколько одинаковых символов подряд (точка). Нужно заменить их на 1 такой символ (....... -> .).

Не все повторяющиеся символы, какой-то конкретный.

Подскажите, какие лучше функции использовать для этого?
Имеет ли смысл использовать ***strtok*** и ***strspn***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и хочется про `gets()` сказать, как маленькому мальчику - "брось каку!" :)

А по сути... берете указатель на начальный символ и идете по строке. Как встретите точку - запоминайте ее, и идите дальше. Если следующий символ *не* точка - забудьте :), если точка - идите дальше, пока не встретите не точку. И копируйте остаток строки с этого символа (с завершающим нулем, само собой) в место за запомненной точкой. И идете дальше - начиная со скопированного символа.

Никаких дополнительных массивов, как видите.

Код написать не сложно, но надо же что-то и вам оставить? :)

**Update**

Ну, если позарез нужно использовать библиотеку - то `strchr` ищет очередную точку, `memmove` копирует остаток строки.

Comment: в том то и дело, что такой код, уже написан, через цикл. Суть состоит именно в использовании функции библиотеки string.h.

Comment: Если точка одна, то и не трогать её, если же точек более чем 1, заменить их на одну

Comment: Ну, тогда гляньте обновленный ответ. Что еще может понадобиться - ума не приложу :)

Comment: вот `strchr` еще смысл понял, а вот по поводу `memmove` так и не понял, как её использовать.

Comment: Поскольку вы при перемещении строки копируете пересекающиеся области, то нужна `memmove`, но не `strcpy`.

Comment: а чем вам так не нравится `gets()`? Имхо - если писать без потоков (там где `cin.getline` то более чем удобна... И да, имхо конечно, но memmove здесь вредит. Сложность из линейной квадратичной становится.

Comment: @pavel Тем, что переполнение буфера сделать - раз плюнуть. Ходило вообще предложение ее из стандарта выбросить, но ограничились строгим deprecated в С99, а выбросили только в С11.. Про `memmove` - без него проще и быстрее... но человеку-то нужны именно функции!